# Regexpr not working as expected

Tags: r, regex

For the following string `<10.16;13.05)` I want to match only the first number (sometimes the first number does not exist, i.e. `<;13.05)`). I used the following regular expression:

```
grep("[0-9]+\\.*[0-9]*(?=;)","<10.16;13.05)",value=T,perl=T)
```

However, the result is not `"10.16"` but `"<10.16;13.05)"`. Could anyone please help me with this one? Thanks.

Comment: What is it supposed to return for `<;13.05)`? 13.05 or nothing?

Comment: Depending on what you want returned for the second case you might try: `sub("[^\\d]([0-9]+\\.*[0-9]*)(?=;).*","\\1", "<10.16;13.05)",perl=T)`

Comment: @MrFlick Nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use `strsplit` here with minimum regex, i.e.

```
x <- '<10.16;13.05)'
as.numeric(gsub('<(.*)', '\\1', unlist(strsplit(x, ';', fixed = TRUE))[1]))
#[1] 10.16

x <- '<;13.05)'
as.numeric(gsub('<(.*)', '\\1', unlist(strsplit(x, ';', fixed = TRUE))[1]))
#[1] NA
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are using the wrong regex function. `grep` just tells you whether the patern was found, it does not extract it.

Try instead

```
regmatches("<10.16;13.05)", regexpr("\\d*\\.\\d*", "<10.16;13.05)"))
```

Comment: But in R help file it says "grep(value = TRUE) returns a character vector containing the selected elements of x"

Comment: @yughred Yes, it does say that. But it **does not** mean what you are thinking. Try `x <- letters[1:4]; grep("b", x, value = TRUE)`. If `x` is a vector, (and it always is one) `value = TRUE` returns the elements of `x` where the pattern was found, as opposed to `value = FALSE` that returns the indices to those elements.